# WPBakery JS composer unused css

Tags: plugins, css

is there a way on how to remove this unused css of /wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/css/js_composer.min.css? It's using so much data without being used.​

[image]

Comment: You could write a hook function to wp_dequeue_style it if you're sure it's not being used. You'd need to find the handle it was enqueued with from the Composer code.

Comment: But you might do better reporting this as a bug against the plugin to see if the authors have a solution. Most page frameworks take pride in how lightweight they are.

Comment: It is using some CSS, just a very little part of the framework I'm trying to remove most of the unused CSS. –